# Access response payload after end in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

If I send a response with

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('okay');
```

is it possible somehow to access the response object and see the actually sent headers and payload?

Comment: I've used [`hijackresponse`](https://github.com/gustavnikolaj/hijackresponse) for this.